# mod_rewrite on substring in URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm forcing HTTPS on my site using mod_rewrite but I want to change this to HTTP for any URL with the substring **com_bookmangement** in the URL.

So

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=85&Itemid=140
```

will be directed to

```
https://www.example.com/index.php??option=com_content&view=article&id=85&Itemid=140
```

BUT

```
https://www.example.com/index.php?option=com_bookmanagement&controller=localbooks&Itemid=216
```

will be directed to

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?option=com_bookmanagement&controller=localbooks&Itemid=216
```

I've tried this without success:

```
#rewrite everything apart from com_bookmanagement to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !443
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !com_bookmanagement=
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

#rewrite vouchers views to http
#RewriteCond %{server_port} 443
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^com_bookmanagement=
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `^com_bookmanagement=` it will only match if `com_bookmanagement=` appears at the start of the string. Try it without the `^` and `=`. Or what I would use:

```
#rewrite everything apart from com_bookmanagement to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)option=com_bookmanagement(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

#rewrite vouchers views to http
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=off
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)option=com_bookmanagement(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Based on his example URLs, he also seems to want to examine `%{QUERY_STRING}` or `%{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING}` instead of just `%{REQUEST_URI}`.

Comment: Yes, usingg QUERY_STRING rather than REQUEST_URI with the above code solved the problem.  Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Condition on `QUERY_STRING` instead of `REQUEST_URI`:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !443
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !com_bookmanagement
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} com_bookmanagement
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

More on rewriting URIs with query strings [here](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString).